# Batch numpy arrays into an array of dictionary entries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of shape (N), and want to get a new array of shape (N, 1) where each entry is a dictionary containing as key the name of its corresponding array and value the array entry at that index. A very inefficient way of doing this is the following:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([-1, -2, -3, -4])

result = []
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    result.append(np.array([{"val_a": a[i], "val_b": b[i]}]))
result = np.array(result)

print(result.shape)
print(result)
```

Which will output:

```
(4, 1)
[[{'val_a': 1, 'val_b': -1}]
 [{'val_a': 2, 'val_b': -2}]
 [{'val_a': 3, 'val_b': -3}]
 [{'val_a': 4, 'val_b': -4}]]
```

Is there a faster way of doing this using numpy functions in a batched way? Consider that N might be very big.

Comment: There is no efficient (vectorial) way to create an object array, your approach is fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a numpy array of dictionaries rather than a structured array?

Comment: `numpy` does nothing special with dicts.  Leave it as as a list.

Comment: Hidden X/Y problem. Why do you need to do this? What are you actually doing with the output afterward?

Comment: The "val_a" and "val_b" keys are repeated N times which is inefficient (not to mention the object type pointed out by previous comments). If all your dictionary contains the same keys like here, then a much better way to store the information is to use *dataframes* (faster and more compact for large data). Pandas does that (and use Numpy internally). Alternatively, you can use Awkward for that. If the number is variable, then lists are better.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement of the "key [being] the name of its corresponding array" feels wrong to me. It is not scalable, and you're hardcoding the variable names in strings.
This leads to inspecting `locals()` and `globals()` for introspection, and that way lies madness.

As an alternative I would suggest to just enumerate the names, in which case using a dict does not give you any advantage over a plain array.
Additionally using a python dict comes with a very big performance hit, because it casts your array to a dtype of object, so I'd just avoid dicts alltogether if you're worried about performance.
If you **really** want names, you could use [structured arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html), like suggested in a comment.

Now you basically just want to zip your arrays.
To reorder your examples, you could then do something like this.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([-1, -2, -3, -4])

combined = np.stack((a, b))
transposed = combined.transpose()

# get val_a and val_b for the second entry
val_a, val_b = transposed[1]
print(val_a, val_b)  # (2, -2)
```

Assuming you did this, here's how you could get the naming done, so the inner arrays act like a dict.

```py
# you need to copy, so the memory is contiguous after transposing
# view reinterprets memory as a different dtype
named = transposed.copy().view([('val_a', int), ('val_b', int)])

my_val_arr = named[1]['val_a']  # array([2])
[val_a] = my_val_arr  # we need to unpack the array
print(val_a)  # 2
```

This does act somewhat different than a normal array, because you need to unpack the result in the end.
But it's **much** faster.

Definitely check the docs for structured arrays though.